# SSL Certificate Generation from CSR and KEY file

Tags: security, rsa, csr, ss

My web host is shutting down - as they have been bought out. I am having difficulty getting my SSL certificate from them.. I am on my 3rd attempt and I have managed to get 2 files.. one I believe is the initial CSR, the Other is my Private Key .KEY file (although the Hosting Provider has been giving me them and claiming they are .crt  - they are not) - that would be my actual Certificate!

I have my CSR file which is headed by  -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----, I have my Private KEY file which is headed by -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

Is there any way fro me to use both of these components to produce my .crt file - I am not sure if my hosting provider (what is left of their support team ) knows the difference between these three files. Of course I am certainly learning myself. I had just purchased that cert from them about 4 months ago and I need it.

> So is there any way I can use my two files .CSR and .KEY to generate
>   my .crt file ?

Comment: No, there is no way, unless it is a self-signed certificate. But you can get the certificate just by connecting to your website.

Comment: @JamesKPolk I did not know that ! I went to the SSL portion of my browser and then exported the certificate to a file and I was then able to upload to my host the Private Key and the CRT file. All seems well currently .. at least for the moment. BTW place that in an answer so I can give you the points.. not that you care but all the same..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to re-create your certificate from the private key and certificate signing request (CSR), unless the certificate was self-signed. However, if the website is still up you can simply connect to the website with [various tools](https://superuser.com/q/97201/23257) and retrieve the certificate that way. Make sure you also retrieve any intermediate certificates as well, although these can almost certainly be obtained from your certificate authority (CA) website as well.